# Is there a way to strike-through active row if value in cell equals declined?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with the following information.

```
First Name      Last Name      Offer Status

John             Smith           Declined

Jane             Anderson        Accepted
```

What code do I need to insert in Excel VBA if I want to strike-through entire active row i.e. values under first name, last name and offer status, if offer status = declined.

Comment: Does it have to be in VBA?  This sounds like something that can be done with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: If I do Conditional Formatting, then I only strike-through cell under "Offer Status". I need to strike-through first and last name too.

Comment: Actually, this can be done with conditional formatting. If you select to use a formula, enter `=$C1="Declined"` with the "C" replaced by whichever column letter has the offer status (and if needed replace the 1 with the first row number to which the conditional formatting is applied). Since there is an absolute marker on the column letter, but not on the row number, the conditional formatting will evaluate each cell based on the value in the _specified_ column of the _relative_ row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with conditional formatting. Just select the entire range you want to apply the condition to. Then add a new rule, and format the cells based on a formula.

The formula would be something like this:

```
=IF($C2="Declined";TRUE;FALSE)
```

In this case I'm assuming that your "Order Status" column is C and your values begin at the second row.

Comment: Actually, the row the values start on is irrelevant in this case. The determining factor is which row the conditional formatting is starting on. If the entire columns (including row 1 are selected) and this equation is used, then the formatting will be on the row **below** the expected row.

Comment: @Mistella You're absolutely right, I was assuming the first lines are headlines and therefore the conditional formatting begins at row 2.

Comment: Note that you could simplify this to `=$C2="Declined"`.